# Navigating with Keys in Terminal Application

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

I am working on a terminal style application in c (on eclipse running on fedora), and I want to use the direction keys to navigate around the program. Does anyone know how to do this while keeping a line in place for the user to enter still text, but have the key presses do other things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it quickly gets ugly coding it.  However, pick up the package [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) and all will become clear.

Basically, the trick is that you must set the terminal device to "raw" mode so you can get the special key sequences directly in your program, then have to interpret them -- they tend to be things like "`<ESC>33;5A`".  Then you need to emit the control sequences that move you around on the screen, and all of these things are device dependent so xterm may differ from gterm and so on.

*ncurses(3)* already hides all that stuff.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) for the software home page, and [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1124) for a tutorial.

Comment: cool, still a bit new to this kind of programming. Do you know of any tutorials buzzing around to get the kind of results I am aiming for?

Comment: cgoddard: Charlie is right. ncurses is absolutely the way to go here. There's no need to drive yourself crazy handling this stuff yourself; ncurses is pretty much the standard way to build text-mode full-screen programs. The docs are good and there are a great many examples of its use a short Google search away. It's been around for over 30 years in one form or another, so you're not missing out on anything by not rolling your own.

Comment: Definitely use `ncurses` or perhaps the `readline` library if working on a single line.